# rusqlite streamline sql select statement

Tags: sqlite, rust, rusqlite

Building app using rusqlite and  many sql (sqlite) statements.

How to streamline the select statement?

Current code:

```rust
let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT pid, cat, plant, variety FROM plants")?;

println!("Columns  = {:?}", stmt.column_names());
println!("column 0 = {:?}", stmt.column_names()[0]);

// ************************MAP the rows using Plant struct
let plant_iter = stmt.query_map([], |row| {
    Ok(Plant {
        pid: row.get(0)?,
        cat: row.get(1)?,
        plant: row.get(2)?,
        variety: row.get(3)?,
    })
})?;

println!(); // ********************ITERATE over the mapped rows using struct
for plant in plant_iter {
    print!(
        "{}{} ",
        plant.as_ref().unwrap().pid,
        " ".repeat(4 - plant.as_ref().unwrap().pid.to_string().len())
    );
    print!(
        "{}{} ",
        plant.as_ref().unwrap().cat,
        " ".repeat(8 - plant.as_ref().unwrap().cat.to_string().len())
    );
    print!(
        "{}{} ",
        plant.as_ref().unwrap().plant,
        " ".repeat(10 - plant.as_ref().unwrap().plant.to_string().len())
    );
    print!(
        "{}{} ",
        plant.as_ref().unwrap().variety,
        " ".repeat(20 - plant.as_ref().unwrap().variety.to_string().len())
    );
}
```

Produces this:

```
Columns  = ["pid", "cat", "plant", "variety"]
column 0 = "pid"

1    veggie   tomato     Brandywine           
2    veggie   bok choy   prize                
3    veggie   cabbage    brunswick
```

Is there a way to get the sqlite format ".mode column" with headers and data all at once with appealing column spacing?

Using the above data can the column headers and rows be combined using rusqlite?

Tried Rusqlite and expected to find a way to emulate sqlite's table view with select statement in rust using rusqlite. Still searching...

Comment: You might want to checkout the [fill & alignment section of the `fmt` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#fillalignment)

Comment: Wow the fill & alignment work just great! Had no idea.

Comment: But still no way to include the headers and data in the iter for printing.